# Every solution of $x''+x+x^3=0$ is set on $\mathbb{R}$ (proof)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, initial-value-problems

*Show that every solution of $x'' + x + x^3 = 0$ is set on $\mathbb R$.*

**Proof:**

If we transform this higher order ode into a system of first order ode's, we get:
$$\vec{x}'=\vec{F}(x)$$
with $$
F_1(x)=x_2, \quad F_2(x)=-x_1-x_1^3$$

Now, since all the partial derivatives of $F$ are continuous within an interval $I=(a,b)$ and thus bounded in $(a,b)$, $\,F$ satisfies a local lipschitz condition in $(a,b)$.

Given that, Picard theorem says that there exists a solution $x(t) \in A$, $t \in(c,d)$ with $A$ a compact set of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Since $F$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R^2}$, $x(t)$ is defined everywhere: $$(c,d)=(-\infty,\infty)$$

Comment: Can you please clarify your notation? What is $f$? Speaking about your question, do you know what is remarkable about systems of form $\ddot{x} = -\nabla F(x)$?

Comment: I meant $F$ (capital). What about these systems?

Comment: See @JohnB answer. Such systems always have a first integral $\frac{1}{2}\langle \dot{x}, \dot{x} \rangle + F(x)$ which for one-dimensional $x$ transforms into $\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2 + F(x)$. I would also add that typically you would like for a trapping compact region: a region in which every trajectory of phase space eventually goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The only problem is the last sentence, nothing in what is before allows you to conclude that.*

The **usual** approach in such problems is to find an integral, such as in this case
$$
E(x,y)=\frac12 y^2+\frac12 x^2+\frac14 x^4
$$
(the sum of the kinetic and potential energies).
Notice that indeed $$\frac{d}{dt} E(x(t),y(t))=0$$ along solutions. Now you only need to note that each level curve of $E(x,y)$ is a bounded set and so all solutions are global (solutions starting in a level curve remain in the same level curve).

Comment: I wanted to ask something about my (failed) attempt: If the Jacobian matrix of $F$ constists of components-functions that are continuous on $\mathbb{R^2}$, does it mean that the solutions of the ode are global (set on $\mathbb{R}$) or not?

Comment: Yes if they are say continuous and bounded. Immediate from the bounds: the solutions cannot "explode" and thus they are global.